# Count of indices in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to fetch the count of indices available in ElasticSearch. Right now i am using /_cat/indices to fetch the list of indices and mapping it with array list and fetching the count. Is there any other API through which I can fetch the count of indices rather than fetching the list and counting it?

Thanks.

Comment: Wondering the same thing. Any update?

Answer (score 3):

```
$ curl <elasticsearch-host-port>/_cluster/stats
```

And then look for indices.count in the response.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using the `_cat/indices` API, you could simply return the results in JSON (instead of tabular form) and then pipe that into `jq` in order to get the length of the index array you get in the response.

```
curl -s localhost:9200/_cat/indices?format=json | jq '. | length'
```

This will return a number equals to the number of indices you have.

Answer (score 0):

GET Call In POSTMAN -> `http://address:9200/_cluster/stats`
OR

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://address:9200/_cluster/stats'
```

===============================

[image]